# How to set groupId to null in @KafkaListeners

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In relation with : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017730/how-to-load-a-compacted-topic-in-memory-before-starting-the-context/56023409)

I'm trying to read a compacted topic via a @KafkaListener.
I'd like every consumers to read the whole topic each time.

I can not generate an unique groupId each for each consumers. So I wanted to use a null groupid.

I've tried to configure the container and the consumer to set the groupId to null, but neither worked.

Here is my Container configuration :

```
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        // Set ackMode to manual and never commit, we are reading from the beginning each time
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        // Remove groupId, we are consuming all partitions here
        factory.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(null);
        // Enable idle event in order to detect when init phase is over
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(1000L);
```

Also tried to force the consumer configuration :

```
Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = sprinfKafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        // Override group id property to force "null"
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, null);
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties);
```

When I'm setting the container groupId to null, a default with the listener id is used.

When I'm forcing the consumer to a null groupId property, I've got an error :
No group.id found in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener annotation; a group.id is required when group management is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a null `group.id`.

From the [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

`group.id`

> A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer belongs to. This property is **required** if the consumer uses either the group management functionality by using subscribe(topic) or the Kafka-based offset management strategy.

If you want to read from the beginning each time, you can either add a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` to the container factory or make your listener implement `ConsumerSeekAware`.

In either case, when `onPartitionsAssigned` is called, seek each topic/partition to the beginning.

> I can not generate an unique groupId each for each consumers.

You can use a SpEL expression to generate a UUID.

**EDIT**

You can manually assign topics/partitions, and the group.id can be null then.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56114299Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56114299Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so56114299", 10, (short) 0);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "so56114299",
                          partitions = "#{@finder.partitions('so56114299')}"))
    public void listen(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String payload) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + payload);
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionFinder finder(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        return new PartitionFinder(consumerFactory);
    }

    public static class PartitionFinder {

        public PartitionFinder(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
            this.consumerFactory = consumerFactory;
        }

        private final ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

        public String[] partitions(String topic) {
            try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer()) {
                return consumer.partitionsFor(topic).stream()
                    .map(pi -> "" + pi.partition())
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual
```

Comment: You can also use a SpEL expression in the `groupId` property to generate a UUID.

Comment: I can not generate an unique groupId due to security and ACL on my broker. I have only a limited amount of groupId I can use and I have to explicitly list all the names.

Comment: Is it possible to not use the "group management functionality" ?

Comment: You can manually assign topics/partitions to listeners instead (using the `topicPartitions` annotation property). It's unwieldy if you have lots of partitions, but manageable if you only have a few.

Comment: Ok I thought I could use a groupId null. What if I create my own kafkaConsumer assigned to all TopicPartitions with "consumer.partitionsFor()" and "consumer.assign()" ?

Comment: Actually, you can do it quite easily with `@KafkaListener` - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I've use your example on a 2 instance-app and though messages were received and listener invoked, there was InvalidGroupIdException in logs. I added a constant identical groupId to both instances and messaged are still received on both pods.  Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to use the same group in this scenario because the instances will interfere with each other’s committed offsets.

Comment: You can disable offset commits by setting the container AckMode to MANUAL and never ack a record.